# PHP rejects image upload in some cases, but I can't figure out why

Tags: php

I have a process whereby I take a picture on a phone and upload it to a PHP script on my server.

It usually works, but *sometimes the phone takes a picture that has SOMETHING about it that the PHP doesn't like.  I have copied the image to my computer and attempted to upload it through a standard browser upload form but get the same error.

My question is, how do I find out what the PHP is not liking about the image? (it appears to be a perfectly legitimate JPG, just like all the others that DO work).

My PHP looks like this:

```
if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $folder . $fileName1 ) ) {
  echo "SUCCESS";       
}
else{           
 "FAIL:";
  foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
           echo "|$name: $value| ";
  }
```

}

I'd like to print and save some error info about what is going wrong here, but am not sure how to introduce what, in effect, would be a catch block in PHP.

All help appreciated.

Comment: If i had to guess I would say your host has a 2mb (or similar) upload limit that you're hitting. Today's camera phones are taking images upwards of that thresh-hold, thus easy to hit the limit.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this was actually the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_FILES array contains a field that describes any error that occurred: $_FILES['file']['error']. You can check them out here http://ca.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the files you are trying to upload are too big?

```
<?php 
if($_FILES['file']['error']) { 
  $Errors .= $_FILES['file']['error'];
} else { 
  // process 
} 
?>
```